# how to make a bootstrap modal window reusuable in vuejs

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, modal-dialog, vuejs2, bootstrap-4

I am trying to create a bootstrap modal window to give a user some sort of warning before performing an action.
When i fill a text field, close the window and i reopen it, the previous values are still showing.
How can I make it such that the text field is a required field and once I close the modal window, the text field clears while obviously storing the value in "reason".
Any help would be appreciated!

Here is my vuejs code:

```js
<div class="modal fade" id="reject" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Loan Rejection</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Are you sure you want to reject this loan request?</p>
              
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Reason: </label>
              <input v-model="reason" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your reason">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal" v-show="reason" @click="clearbox">Reject</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>

 </div>
</template>

<script type="text/javascript">
 export default {
  data () {
   return {
    loanRequest: '',
        reason: ''
   }
  },
    methods: {
      clearbox (){
        reason: ''
      }
    },
  created () {
   this.$http.get('http://localhost:9000/api/loans/hrvalidation')
   .then(
    response => {
     this.loanRequest = response.body
    })
   .catch(function(error){
    console.log(error)
   })
  }
 }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `this.` to access `reason` from inside the method.

Demo: https://codeply.com/go/tjaQKKlHfM

```
 data () {
    return {
        loanRequest: '',
        reason: ''
        }
 },
 methods: {
      clearbox (){
        console.log(this.reason);
        this.reason = null;
      }
 },
```

Comment: Just exactly what I needed!! Thanks a bunch!